# Backwards movement jitery Sprit Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

So i implemented some movement for a character in sprite kit and the forward motion works fine, nice and smooth but when i apply the opposite (-) force the the section for backwards movement it works but looks like there is still a small forward force pushing it which is making it jitter so looks ugly and not smooth,

Here is the code i am using for the all the forces including a gravity and jump (makes for better understanding)

```
 - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta
{
  CGPoint gravity = CGPointMake(0.0, -450.0);
  CGPoint gravityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(gravity, delta);


  //FORWARD MOVE
  CGPoint forwardMove = CGPointMake(800.0, 0.0);
  CGPoint forwardMoveStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(forwardMove, delta);

  //BACKMOVE
  CGPoint BackwardsMove = CGPointMake(-800.0, 0.0);
  CGPoint BackMoveStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(BackwardsMove, delta);

  self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, gravityStep);

  self.velocity = CGPointMake(self.velocity.x * 0.9, self.velocity.y);

  CGPoint jumpForce = CGPointMake(0.0, 310.0);
  float jumpCutoff = 150.0;

  if (self.mightAsWellJump && self.onGround) {
    self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, jumpForce);
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"jump.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
  } else if (!self.mightAsWellJump && self.velocity.y > jumpCutoff) {
    self.velocity = CGPointMake(self.velocity.x, jumpCutoff);
  }

  if (self.forwardMarch) {

    self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, forwardMoveStep);
    CGPoint minMovement = CGPointMake(0.0, -450);
    CGPoint maxMovement = CGPointMake(120.0, 250.0);

    self.velocity = CGPointMake(Clamp(self.velocity.x, minMovement.x, maxMovement.x), Clamp(self.velocity.y, minMovement.y, maxMovement.y));
  }
  if (self.BackwardsMarch) {


    self.velocity = CGPointSubtract(self.velocity, BackMoveStep);
    //self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, BackMoveStep);
    CGPoint minMovement = CGPointMake(0.0, -450);
    CGPoint maxMovement = CGPointMake(-120.0, 250.0);
    //self.velocity = CGPointMake(-16.0, self.velocity.y);

      self.velocity = CGPointMake(Clamp(self.velocity.x, minMovement.x, maxMovement.x), Clamp(self.velocity.y, minMovement.y, maxMovement.y));


  }
  //4

  CGPoint velocityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, delta);

  self.desiredPosition = CGPointAdd(self.position, velocityStep);
}
```

If anyone could clear up what is happening and how to resolve this issue that would be great!

Comment: one thing I would do is if self.forward {} else if self.backwards,  otherwise you may end up in both conditions

Comment: That Condition is covered in my First Touch and touch update so it can't be in both states.

Comment: well for good programming practice I would do it anyway,  it is 1 less check the CPU has to do, and it can't break if the code evolves

Comment: looks like this line `self.velocity = CGPointMake(self.velocity.x * 0.9, self.velocity.y);` could cause you problems, because your sprite always jumps backwards 10% in either direction it is travelling

Comment: I looked at this and thought it might be the cause but wouldn't it effect the jitter in both directions?

as when moving forwards its fine.

Comment: well if you commented it out, did it appear gittery,  it could be just rounding issues that is always shifting right,  so going right looks good, but  going left doesnt

Comment: what i mean is 10.1 in pixel space goes to pixel 11, but we are traveling left, so it really needs to be at 10

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is still forward velocity when you apply the backward velocity, and that is causing the jitters.
When you want to apply the backward velocity first set self.velocity to zero. 
Then apply backward movement.

Comment: I though about that but when i added 

if (self.BackwardsMarch) {
    if (self.velocity.x > 0)
    {
      self.velocity = CGPointMake(0.0, self.velocity.y);
    }
    else {
    
    self.velocity = CGPointSubtract(self.velocity, BackMoveStep);
   ........

It didn't make a Differance

Answer (score 0):

So, i figured it out and @Knight0fDragon was on the right track,

I amended the below code.
And all is working correctly.

```
 if (self.velocity.x >0) {

  self.velocity = CGPointMake(self.velocity.x * 0.9, self.velocity.y);
  }
  else
  {
    self.velocity = CGPointMake(0.0, self.velocity.y);
    self.velocity = CGPointMake(self.velocity.x * 0.9, self.velocity.y);
  }
```